# Preserve timestamp when compressing files with lz4 on linux

Tags: linux, compression

Is there a way to preserve date and time when I compress a file in linux with lz4? The command line looks like this:

```
jens@xyz $ lz4 file file.lz4
```

With e.g. `gzip` the date and time of the compressed file is the same as of the original file. After the command above I could do

```
jens@xyz $ touch -r file file.lz4
jens@xyz $ rm file
```

But that seems a little complicated.

Comment: It's a bug in lz4. It preserves the timestamp but truncates its resolution to 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer combining `lz4` with `tar` if you wish to preserve file properties :

```
compress$  tar cf - file | ./lz4 > file.tar.lz4

decompress$ ./lz4 -d file.tar.lz4 | tar xv
```